# Borel and lebesgue outer measures

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $\mu$ be a Borel outer measure on $\mathbb{R}$, and suppose that for any open interval $I$, we have $\mu(I)  = l(I)$, the length of $I$. Then $\mu(B) = \mathscr{L}(B)$ (a Lebesgue outer measure) for all Borel sets $B$.

I think that the conclusion holds since $\mu$ is an outer measure restricted to  Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $\mathscr{L}$ is an outer measure restricted to $\sigma$-algebra and Borel $\sigma$-algebra is a subset of $\sigma$-algebra. Therefore, these are the same for all Borel sets. Is it correct?

If yes, why do we need the hypothesis that $\mu(I)  = l(I)$?

Could you explain what I am missing here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Let $B$ be the set of Borel sets. Let $\mu:B\to [0,\infty]$ be a countably additive measure such that $\mu(\{1/n\})=1/n$ for $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ and $\mu(S)=0$ if $S\cap \{1/n:n\in \Bbb Z^+\}=\phi.$ Obviously $\mu \ne \mathcal L|_B$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I appreciate if you answer the following questions. Is $S$ the same as $\{1/n\}$? and if not, I am not sure how your answer is related to my question: $\mu(I) = l (I)$.

Comment: In my prior comment, if any  set $S$ is  disjoint from the set of reciprocals of natural numbers then $\mu(S)=0.$ The point is that there is a countably additive measure $\mu$ on $B$ that is different from Lebesgue measure, but $mu(I)$ is generally not $l(I)$ for interval $I$..     So the conclusion, of the theorem that you have quoted, is not valid if the condition $\mu (I)=l(I)$ for every interval $ I$  is omitted.  The point of the theorem is   that if  $\mu$ and $l$ agree on intervals then $\mu=\mathcal L|_B.$